# Is it possible to simulate keyboard events in IOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, keyboard, simulate

I would like to write some sort of macro app that presses keys.  Would this be possible on IOS  and/or Android?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for android, have you tried [MonkeyRunner](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkeyrunner_concepts.html)

> The monkeyrunner tool provides an API for writing programs that
>   control an Android device or emulator from outside of Android code.
>   With monkeyrunner, you can write a Python program that installs an
>   Android application or test package, runs it, sends keystrokes to it,
>   takes screenshots of its user interface, and stores screenshots on the
>   workstation.

Comment: That will only work if the "macro app" is running on a host PC. It will not work if the "macro app" is supposed to run on the device. One application cannot inject key events into arbitrary other apps, for security reasons.